# Создание модели

Tags: javascript, mvc

```
var Model = {

    inherited: function(){},
    created: function(){},
    prototype: {
    init: function(){},
    },

    create: function(){
        console.log(this)
        var object = Object.create(this);
        object.parent = this;
        object.prototype = object.fn = Object.create(this.prototype);
        object.created();
        this.inherited(object);
        return object;
    },
    init: function(){
            var instance = Object.create(this.prototype);
            instance.parent = this;
            instance.init.apply(instance, arguments);
            return instance;
        }
};
var Asset = Model.create();
console.log( Asset )
var User = Model.create();
var user = User.init()
```

Привет. Помогите разобраться с этим кодом.
Мои догадки:
`create()` создает копию исходного объекта `var Model`. Свойство `object.parent` для того что обратится к исходному объекту?
Самое интересное:

```
object.created();

this.inherited(object);
```

То есть мы сможем отслеживать что был `Model.create()` и каждый раз будет вызванные 2 функции?
Зачем:

```
this.inherited(object);
```

и что делает:

`Model.init()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ф-ия `create`:

```
var object = Object.create(this);
```

Создание объекта, унаследованного от указанного объекта.

Т.е. смотрим, как работает `Object.create:`

```
Object.create = function(pr) {
    function Func() {}
    Func.prototype = pr;
    return new Func();
};
```

Дальше:

```
object.prototype = object.fn = Object.create(this.prototype);
```

Видимо такая штука, которая в дальнейшем даст такую фичу, как добавление различных методов созданному объекту.

```
object.parent
```

Указываем родителя.

```
this.inherited(object);
```

Метод, который получает созданный объект.

В итоге что: метод `create` возвращает новый объект, унаследованный у объекта `Model`

ф-ия `init`:

```
init: function(){
    var instance = Object.create(this.prototype);
    instance.parent = this;
    instance.init.apply(instance, arguments);
    return instance;
}
```

- создали объект
- задали родителя
- вызвали метод `init` нашего нового объекта, который мы создали в первой строке с контекстом `instance` (т.е. задали `this == instance` внутри ф-ции `init`) и существующими аргументами.

Т.е. функция `init` возвращает новый объект, унаследованный у `Model.prototype` (`Object.create(this.prototype)`). Или экземпляр объекта `Model`.

Comment: Спасибо.Хоть дальше смогу книгу лопатить.

Comment: @koza4ok вы случаем не "веб приложения на javascript, руководство jquery программиста" читаете?

Comment: ДА.Заумная книга для меня.Каждый пример на вес золота там ,ено и мозги там нужны.Не знаеш похожую книгу на английском по созданию модулей...?

Comment: @koza4ok Я вообще книги не читаю) Если что-то понадобилось - изучаю по статьям как на офф. сайтах, так и тематических. Там нет такой воды, как в книгах на 300 страниц.

Comment: наверно нужно на stackoverflow еще пошарить

Comment: @koza4ok хотя я и не отрицаю, что книги чем-то хуже статей. Книга скорее всего учит, а статья просто объясняет.